# How to let -1==-1.0000000000001

Tags: c++, c, math, approximation

Here is a part of my code:

```
double tmp = OP.innerProduct(OQ);
double tmp2 = -1;
```

and the value of `tmp` and `tmp2` is: (in binary)

```
tmp = 0b1011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
tmp2= 0b1011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If I used `acos(tmp)`, it will return `nan`.

I don't want the `nan` value, and I would like to ignore the small error to keep `tmp` in the range [-1,1].

How to do so?

**EDIT:**

I have two points given in spherical coordinate. ( for example, (r,45,45) (r,225,-45) )

Then I need to change them to cartesian coordinate. (a small error occur here!)

Then I want to compute the angle between two points.

**The analytical solution is different to computer solution(since the small error).
I would like to make the two solutions same.**

Comment: Do you see any problem with code that matches your last sentence (`if (ValueAlmostInsideRange(tmp)) { tmp = ClipValue(tmp);}` )? Or you are seeking for some other help?

Comment: *How to let -1==-1.0000000000001* `if (-1 == int(-1e-013))` ?

Comment: Any error in converting to Cartesian coordinates is irrelevant to the `acos` domain problem. After the conversion, you have two points with Cartesian coordinates. Even if they are not the mathematically exact values from an ideal conversion, they are still actual points in space, and the cosine of the angle between them is in [–1, 1]. Therefore, the error would be in calculating (as with dot product divided by distances from origin) the cosine of the angle between them.

Comment: Note that there is no angle between two points. I presume you want the angle formed by rays to the two points from the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to prevent branching?  I usually make a little helper when I'm doing anything like this:

```
template<typename T>
inline T Clamp( T val, T low, T high ) {
    return val < low ? low : (val > high ? high : val);
}
```

And then:

```
double result = acos( Clamp(tmp, -1.0, 1.0) );
```

If you're trying to write highly optimized code without branching, this won't help.  Depending on the accuracy you require, you might consider making an `acos` lookup table and just put an extra value at each end to handle error-induced overflow.

[edit] I've just had a play around with a [-1,1] clamp without branching.  Of course, this only cures inaccuracies.  If you call it with a number that is grossly outside the range, it will bomb:

```
inline double safer_acos (double val)
{
    double vals[] = {-1.0, val, val, 1.0};
    return acos( vals[int(2.0 + val)] );
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna guess that most implementations of acos are going to contain enough branching that this extra branch isn't going to matter much.

Comment: Also note that since comparison against -1.0 and 1.0 is exact for floating point numbers none of the comments in other posts about tolerances and inexactness apply here.

Comment: Cheers.  You're probably right about the speed of `acos` versus the performance loss in our own branching, but just for fun I added a branchless numerical clamp.